# How to translate the "select" field with ACF for Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I created a “select” field with ACF. Only, my site has several languages.

For example, I create a select field with these data :

green : Green
black : Black

green is the key, Green is the value. These fields must be translated into 4 languages. And there will be several (one hundred).

I wish I could translate the data. I tried to put directly into the select field `<? php _e ('Green', 'myChain');?>` But it does not work.

I use Polylang. I tried with WPML but I do not like this plugin. And then, it does not work well (I have to select each time on the other pages translated the values that I had selected on the original page)

That’s why I just want to translate the string? Is it possible ? There will be many.

Thank you very much !

Comment: you could have it in english in the backend, and translate it your way in the output?

Comment: <? php _e (get_field('whatever'), 'myChain');?>

Comment: @Stender I had not thought of this solution. I will test. Thank you !

Comment: @Stender it does not seem to work, it does not spot the string